# Initially rendering a page with a bs_theme() can be very slow for large shiny apps

Tags: r, shiny

I've been trying out the `bslib` package and hit some trouble using it to style a somewhat bloated shiny app I've developed. It takes about 30 seconds before anything at all gets rendered in the browser. However if I switch to using a `shinythemes` theme instead then there is no delay.

I've recreated the issue with a simple app with an inordinate number of selectize inputs. The time before rendering seems roughly proportional to the number of inputs.

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = bs_theme(bootswatch = "slate"),
  # theme = shinythemes::shinytheme("slate"),
  do.call("tagList", lapply(1:200, function(x) 
    selectInput(paste0("id", x), "Another input", choices = LETTERS)))
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Anyone have any ideas what it is doing, or if there is a way around this?

Comment: Profiling the app with `profvis` (`profvis(runApp(shinyApp(ui, server)))`) shows that `bs_dependency` is the culprit. Not sure if it would help you to preload `theme` outside of the `ui.r` (e.g. in `global.r`), then starting an instance of the app would be faster.

Comment: Thanks, I can't get it to preload like that. I did try different inputs and only the selectize input has this problem so far - in fact if you put `selectize = FALSE` in the above it is quick again.

Comment: Hi @pseudospin Wondering whether you found a solution to bslib being very slow?